# Firebase Realtime Database - Remove all children but keep the parent

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Realtime Database, I have a parent node, "Name" and two children shown below.

[image: Firebase Data]

I want to be able to remove the two child nodes but still keep the parent node.
This way, I can make a database that can add names and remove names.
Is there a way to create a parent node starting with zero children?

Answer (score 5):

You can't have a node in Realtime Database with no children of its own.  Removing the last child will cause the node to cease to exist.

If you want the node to exist again, simply write a child value to it.  You don't have to create it first - it will simply begin to exist the moment you write to it.